# Facebook request_ids don't show in notification bar

Tags: facebook, request, apprequests, facebook-app-requests

After I create request using apprequest dialog, it appears in notification bar and on the right side on main facebook page. On the right side, link to application looks like this

```
http://apps.facebook.com/12354897899498/?fb_source=reminders&request_ids=224231197698079%2C298010856961088&ref=reminders
```

But when i click it from notification bar (top left) the url goes like this

```
http://apps.facebook.com/12354897899498/
```

So no `request_ids` is delivered. Do you know why this happens? Is it bug?

I know I can get all request for user through Graph API, but I need rights to do it.

Comment: I can not reproduce the behavior you are describing.  Acting on an application request from **anywhere** appends the `request_id` to the URL...

Answer (score 0):

You have to get basic permissions from a user in order to do ANYTHING with the `request_ids`.  You will have to authenticate new users in order to monitor their `request_ids`.

I wouldn't want any application (that I haven't authorized yet) to have access to my pending requests.